# MySQL Query: Query All Entries Older Than 1 Year

Tags: mysql

I am putting together a membership database for a nonprofit charity in LibreOffice, but have no experience in mysql queries so I would appreciate the help.

I am trying to create a query that displays all records where the membership signup date field (*PaymentDate*) is older than 1 year of the current date **AND** a boolean value of another field (*AwaitingRenewal*) is NO. The date is in *05/03/85* format. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like:

```
select * from `members` 
  where `paymentDate` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  and `AwaitingRenewal` = 'NO'
```

Comment: I get "The Data Could Not Be Loaded: Table Not Found in Statement" I double checked all the table and column names and they are correct.

Comment: You might have to put the table and field names in quotes.

Comment: Do you know the name of the database you are trying to ask.  This is a valid SQL statement.  You might have to use `name_of_db.members` instead of members.

Comment: If i do that I get an invalid schema name error. This is really perplexing me.

Comment: If anyone could see what I'm doing wrong I would REALLY appreciate it... it's also how I learn best.

http://www.clevelandnorml.org/assets/files/Membership_Database.odb

Comment: Are you sure that you are using mySQL?   What happens if you use another tool such as Toad to access it and run the query?

Comment: This was solved by the fact that the version of mysql was an older one. Pardon me for not answering faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
* from dt_tb where `dt` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

My attention was drawn to this question because another similar question was closed citing this question as a duplicate. But I don't feel that any of these answers addressed either question *completely* and so I wanted to add one point I felt was missing.

A `DATE` or `DATETIME` column carries no time zone information yet when one calls the MySQL `CURDATE` or `NOW` function to get respectively the current date or date and time, the values returned are always with respect to the current session time zone that is in effect. So one has to ask how did the original column value get set to begin with? Was it with a call to `CURDATE` or `NOW` and if so, was the session time zone that was in effect then the same as the one in effect now? Or if the column had been set with a literal such as `'2020-03-01'` or `'2020-03-01 03:00:00'`, what *implicit* time zone did the setter have in mind when creating that literal? Again, is it the same time zone that is set for the current session?

It is only if the current session time zone is set to the same time zone that was either explicitly or implicitly in effect when the column that is being compared with the current date or date and time that the MySQL function `DATE_SUB` will give you the correct results (or alternatively, if you know the difference in hours between these two time zones, you can then adjust the results returned by `DATE_SUB` by that difference).

Consequently, if you need to store date-time info where later on you will be asking questions such as did this date-time happen more than a year ago, a `DATEIME` column is a poor choice of data type just because it carries no time zone information. Had this column type been instead a `TIMESTAMP` initialized to `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`, then internally the data would have been *in effect* (although not exactly) converted to UTC time and thus would have an implicit UTC time zone. Subsequently when the column is compared to `CURDATE()` or `NOW()` or used with a function such as `DATE_SUB`, it will be automatically converted back to the current time zone that is in effect for the session and you will get the correct result.

In this particular example, however, we are dealing with a `DATE` column. Let's say it was initialized with `CURDATE()` and at the time the default session time zone was being used, which was `America/Los_Angeles'`. Some time later you moved to a different server and now the current default session time zone is `'America/New_York'`. If you really care about the 3 hour difference and want to be as accurate as possible (and assuming you realize that there has been this change in time zones) then you need to set the correct session time zone for which the `DATE` column should be interpreted:

```
set session time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
select * from `members` 
  where `paymentDate` < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  and `AwaitingRenewal` = 'NO'
```

Or once and for all you can "fix" your database by converting the `paymentDate` column to a `TIMESTAMP` column (even though you will only be storing `CURDATE()` values, which will have implicitly `00:00:00` time values) with:

```
set session time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
alter table `members` change `paymentDate` `paymentDate` timestamp not null;
```

And then you never have to be concerned about what your current session time zone is as long as your are comparing the `paymentDate` column with a value that has time zone information such as is returned by `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`. But you may now have to use the `DATE` function against the column to suppress the result having a time component, even though it is `00:00:00`:

```
select * from `members` 
  where DATE(`paymentDate`) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
  and `AwaitingRenewal` = 'NO'
```

But there is one more thing to be aware of if you do this conversion. The `TIMESTAMP` column (`pyamentDate`) will display by converting the internal value to the current session time zone whatever that is whereas the original `DATE` column displayed totally independent of the current session time zone.