# MYSQL SELECT records older than 1 year ago

Tags: php, mysql, date

I try to get a list of all records that are older than 1year ago from my database, the field for expired_contract has next information.

```
expired_contract DATE NOT NULL
```

So it takes the DATE in the next format: YEAR-MM-DD, next i have the sql that i cant get it working sadly.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM My_Contracte 
        WHERE expired_contract >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
        ORDER BY id_contract DESC";
```

I tried a lot of "WHERE" commands but none worked as i expected. Can you help me get this working? I'm looking on this for about 5hours i need exact command to get it worked.

The $sql gets me something but takes it wrong, i get dates like: 2015-10-01, 2016-10-01 and date like 2014-09-30 doesn't show up.

Basically i want to show dates like:

If today is 2015-10-01 i want to see dates older than 1year ago so from 2014-09-30 and not showing dates like 2015-10-01, 2016-10-01.

Maybe do i have to edit something in database?

Looking for your help, thank you!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12736181/128161

Comment: It's working, thank you man!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have to use lower than instead of greater or equals:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM My_Contracte WHERE expired_contract < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(impressions) AS impressions FROM My_Contracte  where DATE(expired_contract) BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 1 YEAR ) AND CURDATE( )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM My_Contracte WHERE (expired_contract NOT BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE()) and expired_contract<=NOW() ;
```

Comment: Yep, but your function takes also from year 2017 or so. I got it worked with  Jens and Jamie help. I thank you also for help.